# CKEditor - how to tailor it to one's needs?

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using a demo version of CK Editor. While it does what it is meant to, I find several annoyances I thought you guys might have found a way to overcome.
What hurts:

1. The output code quite messy. It prepends the text with empty
   `<p>&nbsp;</p>` lines which are not rendered initially, not until
   you toggle Source code back and forth. (The line break treatment
   setting does not seem to matter here)
2. The output code is very white-spacey (too many tabs indents and line-breaks)
3. The module itself seems not too much configurable (default format "Normal DIV" being useless in most of my cases - but I cannot set other default).
4. It unnecessarily converts some of the HTML-safe characters into entities (such as `&oacute;`) while leaving out others not necessarily HTML-safe (like Eastern European accented characters, the equivalent of `&deg;` or Greek symbols).

On the whole, operating it requires very much clicking, toggling, proofing and using support tools like Dreamweaver or NetBeans.

But this is the out-of-the-box state. Perhaps someone has managed to tailor the editor and its behaviors to their needs, via js or whatever it supports and can shed the light on how to do that?

Comment: Which module are you talking about? [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or [Wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)? Both provide a means to integrate the CKEditor into Drupal.

Comment: Are you talking about CKEditor in general?  Or specifically the Drupal module?  It sounds to me as if it's the former.

Comment: Oswald: CK Editor; Chapabu: I mean Drupal, although I guess if I were to tweak it, I would have to change CKE's core.